# Rails 3. Destroy only one field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have fiels username, name, surname, password, email. And how to set username and password fields to null?
Thank you

Comment: Be more precise. What do you mean by destroying? Drop the whole table column? Or set only username and e-mail in all entries to null?

Comment: set username and password to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `obj` is an instance of your `User` (?) model.

```
obj.username = nil
obj.password = nil
obj.save
```

This will set the username and password fields to null (`nil`) and update the record in the database

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.update_attributes!(:username => nil, :password => nil)
```